# I do the eas build --platform android comes out an error like this

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'amonisasi'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
> Required by:
> project : > project :react-native-gradle-plugin

how to fix this error

Comment: Please elaborate the things you did before that error occurred. Sometimes, error messages aren't enough to determine the cause of an error. If that error involves some code, please share that as well

Comment: Was you able to solve this? I'm getting the same problem